# cakephp Tree behavior remove parent node except children

Tags: php, cakephp, tree, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

Is it possible to remove the parent node from a Tree using [CakePHP Tree Behavior?](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1339/Tree). Let's say for example I have a node like this:

```
<Node A>
    - child 1 node A
    - child 2 node A
    - child 3 node A
    - <Node B> (which is also a child 4 of Node A)
        - child 1 node B
        - child 2 node B
```

Is it possible to get all the chidren of Node A (using the chidren() or any other function of the Tree behavior in cakePHP), but exclude a node which has children from the result (in our case Node B)?

Any idea please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can but you'll need to get your hands a bit dirty because I don't think the behavior allows anything like this.

The key is that all nodes that do not have children should have a `left` and `right` value that are in sequence. You'll need to whip up a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE left > (parent's left) AND right < (parent's right) AND right = left + 1 AND parent_id = (parent's ID)
```

That way we're asking that all returned values are children of our parent and that their left and right values are in sequence, which they won't be if a node has children.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at specifications there is no specific method for this, so you must build your own function for that using children() and childCount(). Here's the code template (I don't use Cake PHP):

```
$children = <call TreeBehavior children() method with $id = id of Node A and $direct = true>;
$children_without_children = array();
foreach ($children as $child) {
    if (<call TreeBehavior childCount() method with $id = $child->id and $direct = true> === 0) {
        $children_without_children[] = $child;
    }
}
```

Then $children_without_children should contain what you want.

Comment: For very large result sets this will involve a **lot** of hits against the database. Also, if you have the child record on hand you could just check that the left and right values are sequential, negating the need for any DB hit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
$this->Node->removeFromTree($id, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code from my cakephp 2.x project:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->ProductCategory->id = $id;
        if (!$this->ProductCategory->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid product category'));
        }
        $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->ProductCategory->removeFromTree($id, TRUE)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product category has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product category could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

Using this method (e.i. removeFromTree ()) will either delete or move a node but retain its sub-tree, which will be reparented one level higher. It offers more control than delete, which for a model using the tree behavior will remove the specified node and all of its children.